# Creating an independent form for a model that belongs to a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So I have two models `Room` and `Reservation`.

The `Room` object is created beforehand by someone who owns the room and is stored in the database.

I want to allow a different user to later on create a reservation (on a different page and completely separate form) that *belongs_to* that particular room, so that way when I want to pull up a list of reservations for that room, I can simply do something like `@room.reservations`.

I want the room to be created in the `RoomsController` and the reservations to be created in the `ReservationsController`.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do this the "Rails way". The best I have come up with is:

```
# .../rooms/new
= form_for @room, room_path do |f|
    # Form that creates a room

# .../reservations/new
= form_for @reservation, reservation_path do |f|
    # Form that creates a reservation
```

But when I do it this way, I have no way (at least that I know) of referring to a **specific** listing in the `ReservationsController`.

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    # What I want to do:
    @listing = Listing.new(params[:id])   # no way of getting Listing's id
    @reservation = @listing.reservations.build(reservation_params)

    # etc...
```

I thought I could include it as a hidden field in the `reservations` form, but I don't have a way to validate it. I tested that by filling out the form and then changing the hidden input field's params[:id] value in Chrome's Inspect Element, which of course will post it to a different room, which is not desirable.

I am now stuck doing this:

```
# I ended up having to create a "reserve" action in the listings controller

= form_for @listing, :url => { :controller => "listings", :action => "reserve" } do |f|
    f.fields_for :reservation do |r|
        # All the fields to create a reservation here...
```

Which is not at all what I want. I want to be able to utilize my `ReservationsController`.

How do I realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested route:

```
resources :rooms, shallow: true do
  resources :reservations
end
```

This nests the "collection routes" for reservations in the context of a Room.

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
   room_reservations GET    /rooms/:room_id/reservations(.:format)     reservations#index
                     POST   /rooms/:room_id/reservations(.:format)     reservations#create
new_room_reservation GET    /rooms/:room_id/reservations/new(.:format) reservations#new
    edit_reservation GET    /reservations/:id/edit(.:format)           reservations#edit
         reservation GET    /reservations/:id(.:format)                reservations#show
                     PATCH  /reservations/:id(.:format)                reservations#update
                     PUT    /reservations/:id(.:format)                reservations#update
                     DELETE /reservations/:id(.:format)                reservations#destroy
               rooms GET    /rooms(.:format)                           rooms#index
                     POST   /rooms(.:format)                           rooms#create
            new_room GET    /rooms/new(.:format)                       rooms#new
           edit_room GET    /rooms/:id/edit(.:format)                  rooms#edit
                room GET    /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#show
                     PATCH  /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#update
                     PUT    /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#update
                     DELETE /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#destroy
```

You then would need to alter your ReservationsController to use `params[:room_id]` to find the room when creating a reservation:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reservation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_room, only: [:new, :create]

  # GET /rooms/:room_id/reservations
  def index
    @room = Room.includes(:reservations).find(params[:room_id])
    @reservations = @room.reservations.all
  end

  # GET /rooms/:room_id/reservations/new
  def new
    @reservation = @room.reservations.new
  end

  # POST /rooms/:room_id/reservations
  def create
    @reservation = @room.reservations.new(reservation_params)

    if @reservation.save
      redirect_to @reservation, notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ... The rest of the controller actions

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_reservation
      @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_room
      @room.find(params[:room_id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:room_id, :starts_at, :ends_at)
    end
end
```

And you need to slightly alter the form so it posts to `/rooms/:room_id/`:

```
= form_for([@room, @reservation]) do |f|
   # ... fields go here
```

There is no need to include the room id in the form since we get it from the request url.

Comment: Notice that I use `Room`, since you are not really clear about what `Listing` means in your application. The same principles apply nonetheless.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I did mean "Room" instead of "Listing"! I am going to give this a whirl and see how it works out for me, but just by looking at it, I can already tell that this might be the right answer for me.

Comment: This is the demo Rails app I used to generate the code for the answer: https://github.com/maxcal/sandbox/tree/31526836